# Can KDE's system monitor widget be tweaked to look like this one in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, panel, system-monitor

Compare Gnome (with "dash-to-panel"):

[image]

and KDE:

[image]

and notice the differences:

Gnome shows a nice multicolored system usage widget, where graphs flow slowly to the left, memory usage and file system cache in different colors (deep and light green). You can show CPU, RAM, network, disk and GPU usage in a consistent way.

On the other hand, KDE flickers some useless thing that's liable to give you a seizure (a static screenshot doesn't do justice to how distracting this thing is -- it's switching between fonts several times per second)

Can I get KDE to look like the above Gnome panel (preferably without having to install some third-party binary blobs -- it's a question of trust) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the widget and choose the type of visualization, and edit lots of parameters in it. Just right click it and go for the widget settings.

Comment: You can edit the parameters, but that doesn't mean you can make it look like Gnome.